# strange problem with audio

Tags: audio, kde, kde-neon

I don't know exactly how to describe the problem. I've had it for a while and I haven't found any response from teachers or from any forum I have reviewed

I started using linux for a while now, but I have a constant problem with any distro: when I'm playing an audio every x time it locks (it doesn't stop, it loops like a scratched cd), this is added to that every time that I connect the headphones to the PC and play an audio, a blow is heard in the main speakers of the PC (not my headphones) (the audio stroke is like when you connect something to an amplifier, that "pop").

I have used ubuntu 18.04LTS, mint 19.3 and I am currently using kde neon 5.18 and in none of these distros I have stopped having that problem, and in windows everything is perfect

(I don't know if necessary but I have a Lenovo C40-30)

Comment: Ok, let's tackle them one by one. Is the locking of the sound reproducible with a specific track (one that works in the other system)? If yes, does it change if you use another media player? (you might want to try `aplay`, `mplayer`, `vlc`, ...

Comment: the problem is constant, it happens with music, youtube, discord and with any audio in general

Comment: The idea is to narrow down and isolate the problem. Say you can reproduce it with `mplayer`, then you run it with verbose output to find out what is happening when the sound stops. You could then check the system logs, or change the virtual output device. Is there anything about sound in the system logs, for example when you do `sudo dmesg`? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: I don't really know how to do it, or verify what he told me.
I am really new to Linux. barely 2 months ago I used it

Comment: You are experiencing drop outs/bad data when some process that's supposed to deliver or process audio stalls. There are many possible reasons why this could happen. The first step is to narrow down if the problem is with Pulseaudio, or on the ALSA/hardware level. You can manually stop Pulseaudio (`pasuspender`) and then run `aplay` on a WAV file to test ALSA, and see if the problem persists. If you are a Linux newbie, this may be too difficult for you; try to find someone with more experience who can do this together with you.

Comment: watching a video on how to use pulseaudio I fixed the problem of pop :D now only follows the problem that from time to time the audio is repeated as when a cd is scratched